# How to use bash variables inside a Python code?

Tags: python, bash

I wanna do this:

```
    import subprocess 
    subprocess.call(['var="foo_bar"'], shell=True)
    subprocess.call(['echo $var'], shell=True)
```

But when i will use the $var in the second line your value is losted.

Somebody know some say to solve this problem?
This is a simple example, but a need to do that in a much more complex code here..

Tks..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inject the value into the environment with `os.environ`.

```
os.environ['var'] = "foo_bar"
subprocess.call(['echo $var'], shell=True)
```

Comment: Also look at the `env` parameter to `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.call`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can use enviroment variables (`os.environ`), and you can of course use everything you get passed as command line args (`sys.argv`), but bash variables are bash variables and not Python variables. You'll have to find another way (perhaps we could suggest a way if you told us what exactly you want to do).